# ngCart checkout button always 404s

Tags: angularjs

I feel like I am being stupid.

in the docs it says ngCart will render a checkout button with this:

```
 <ngcart-checkout service="http" settings="{ url:'/checkout' }"></ngcart-checkout>
```

However this returns a 404. I have setup my checkout view and added to the routeprovider (which works with a normal link)

I have also tried variations (add hashbang etc) and links to non-angular pages but everything 404s

ngCart's example seem to invoke the checkout button like so:

```
 <div ng-if="service=='http' || service == 'log'">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="checkout()" ng-disabled="!ngCart.getTotalItems()" ng-transclude>Checkout</button>
 </div>
```

This returns: provider.checkout is not a function - expected as I haven't declared it. But I wouldn't know where to start with creating a function to open the checkout page.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this:

```
<ngcart-checkout service="http" settings="{ url:'/#/checkout' }"></ngcart-checkout>
```

Also for ngCart, you'll have to add some more information to your settings object. Such as your paypal email, order items, total price, etc. See the [docs](http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs).

Comment: This still returns a 404. It was also my understanding that the checkout button automatically sends a Object with all the cart information in (as checkout log button does). so no other settings are required.

Answer (score 0):

Stupidity resolved:

Its a post request - which needs to go to the server. You can add ng-href="" to the checkout button inside the template files to progress to the checkout page.